# How to import old version of database file into a new version?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

In my application the user can export and import his database file for backup the data.I updated the database version and added some more new columns. now, probebly the user backup the old database of version 1.
and after he will try to import he is going to get something like "(1) no such column: (And the Column name here)".
How can i call the onUpgrade on old database after import?
Can i call onUpgrade on the loaded databae manually?
How can i solve it?
Do i need to tell the users after they update the application to do fresh backup again for safe?
Any idea anyone?

the code how i do import:

```
// importing database
public boolean importDB(String path , File dbFile) {
    try {
        boolean isValid = checkDbIsValid(dbFile);
            if(!isValid){
                Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorFile),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

        //Last loaded file name will be the auto backup file destination
        int lastIndexOf = path.lastIndexOf('/');
        String loadedFileName = path.substring(lastIndexOf + 1);
        new MySharedPreferences(context).putStringLastFileNameSent(loadedFileName);


        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
        //Destination to:
        String outFileName = DATABASE_DIRECTORY + DbContract.DB_NAME;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();

        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.importDatabaseSucceed),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(context,context.getResources().getString(R.string.errorImportDatabase),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this How i check if the datbase file is valid:

```
public static boolean checkDbIsValid(File db) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDb;
        Cursor cursor;
        try {   
             sqlDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase (db.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_NONE);
             cursor = sqlDb.query(true,DbContract.TABLE_DAY, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
             for( String s : DbContract.ALL_COLUMN_KEYS_IN_TABLE_DAY){
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(s);
             }

            //This make sure the user can import old database on new Version of table
            try {
                cursor = sqlDb.query(true,DbContract.TABLE_SETTING,null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                for( String s : DbContract.ALL_COLUMN_KEYS_IN_TABLE_SETTING_v2){
                    cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(s);
                }
                System.out.println("DATABASE LOADED FROM V2");
            }catch (Exception fileNotV1){
                System.out.println("ERROR FILE .. IS NOT V2");
                try {
                    for( String s : DbContract.ALL_COLUMN_KEYS_IN_TABLE_SETTING_v1){
                        cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(s);
                    }

                    System.out.println("DATABASE LOADED FROM V1");
                }catch (Exception fileNotV2){
                    System.out.println("ERROR FILE .. IS NOT V1");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if(DbContract.VERSION<sqlDb.getVersion() ){
                return false;
            }
            sqlDb.close();
            cursor.close();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DbContract.DB_NAME, null, DbContract.VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DbContract.CREATE_TABLE_WORKS);
        db.execSQL(DbContract.CREATE_TABLE_SETTING);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion == 1) {
            updateToVersion2(db);
        }
    }

    public void updateToVersion2(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DbContract.TABLE_SETTING + " ADD "
                + DbContract.COLUMN1 + " REAL DEFAULT 1");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DbContract.TABLE_SETTING + " ADD "
                + DbContract.COLUMN0 + " REAL DEFAULT 0");
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DbContract.TABLE_SETTING + " ADD "
                + DbContract.COLUMN2 + " REAL DEFAULT 0");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you describe how you are exporting and importing the data? Are you literally copying the database file to and from some other storage location? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: I take the db file from the app data/data... and copy it to my local storage. and for import i just override the existing file

Answer (score 1):

If you are literally copying the db file to and from storage, then in theory when you call `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWriteableDatabase()`, it should check the database version and go through the typical upgrade flow, which calls [`onUpgrade()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int)) and gives you both the old and new version numbers. If that's the case, and if you are properly implementing `onUpgrade()`, then things should "just work".

If the upgrade isn't happening automatically, after opening the database you can check the database version yourself with [`getVersion()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#getVersion()) and perform any commands you like to upgrade the schema manually.

**EDIT**

In order for `onUpgrade()` to run automatically, you need to open the database using your `DbHelper` class. Absent that, you need an instance of `DbHelper` so that you can call its `onUpgrade()` method and pass it the `SQLiteDatabase` you opened manually.

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlDb = ...;
DbHelper dbHelper = ...;
dbHelper.onUpgrade(sqlDb, sqlDb.getVersion(), DbContract.VERSION);
```

I'm not particularly fond of your method to check if the DB file is valid. You would have to keep track of every schema version in your contract and check each one; that seems unwieldy. What if instead you copy the file into a temp file in your app's database directory, open it with a `DbHelper` (which should try to open it), and if anything fails you can abort and delete the file? If it succeeds, you can just rename the file and reopen the database. That's probably how I would approach it.

Comment: Please look above. i update my question..Can you please help me and show me where and how i need to call the onUpgrade?

Comment: I think i fix it i just check if the "Loaded" database file is lower version from the current Version and then i call "onUpgrade" manually like this:
   `if(DbContract.VERSION!=sqlDb.getVersion()) {
//    System.out.println("Database loaded is older from current version so i upgrade to the current");
    new DbHelper(mContext).onUpgrade(sqlDb, sqlDb.getVersion(), sqlDb.getVersion());
   }`
This is look like it works but this is the right way to do it?

Comment: @Anna the last argument should technically be the version you are upgrading to (i.e. `DbContract.VERSION`), though it might not matter based on your implementation of `onUpgrade()`

Comment: i'm not really use the "newVersion" argument. it's importent?

Comment: @Anna No, but if you ever do start using it, it would be nice if it were correct, and the change is simple enough.